# How can I set default hover::after/active state?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Got a css animation for underlining, but setting:

```
<button className="btn active">
```

doesnt seem to have the end of the animation set as default. Can someone hint me what i'm doing wrong? Here's my CSS:

```
.btn {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: whitesmoke;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: white;
}

.btn:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.btn::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.105rem;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: whitesmoke;
  transform: scale(0, 1);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to achive?

Comment: That what yo want you can achive with javascript, tu use  ::after is used fore different purpose, you are setting transform and transition inside after, which does not make sence... The after is to describe position relative to the element and it is not an event..

Comment: or you can use dellay transition-delay: 250ms;
transition-property: margin-right;

Comment: Trying to make className='active' set the button as underlined

Comment: set   background-color:black; to the .btn  the problem you have it is a bad contrast...

Comment: the css works its a contrast issue

Comment: nope, still doesnt remain active

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: whitesmoke;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: white;
}
/* Expected selector ".btn::after" to come before selector ".btn:hover::after" */
.btn::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.105rem;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: whitesmoke;
  transform: scale(0, 1);
}
/* Expected selector ".btn::after" to come before selector ".btn:hover::after" */
.btn:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}



.btn:active {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn active">Button</button>
```

Comment: Hmmm, but id like to set the button to be already underlined as default with className="active"